# python requests with API

Tags: python

I want POST request on hetzner API

```
POSTPTR = requests.post('https://robot-ws.your-server.de/rdns/123.123.123.123', params="-d ptr=server.domain.com", auth=(USER, PASS)) 
DATE_INF = POSTPTR.json()
print DATE_INF
```

appear to me this error

```
{u'error': {u'status': 400, u'message': u'invalid input', u'code': u'INVALID_INPUT', u'invalid': None, u'missing': [u'ptr']}}
```

I want do this command but with requests

```
curl -u user:password https://robot-ws.your-server.de/rdns/123.123.123.123 -d ptr=testen.de
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: can u help about this?

Comment: Help with what? Try to phrase your question in the form of a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
resp = requests.post('https://robot-ws.your-server.de/rdns/123.123.123.123', data={'ptr':'testen.de'}, auth=(USER, PASS))
```

Comment: Glad to help ya :)